# How to restore (normalize) HDD spinoff timeout in LXLE?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, power-management, ubuntu-18.04, disk-management

After the last update on my system, the timeout setting for turning off the hard disk was broken.
This problem manifests itself as a constant shutdown and spinning of the HDD motor at intervals of about 10-20 seconds.

The hard drive itself is still alive, but with such treatment it will not live long. I made sure the drive is working, connect my laptop to the charger. Once I did that, the problem with shutting down the disk was gone. It seems the disk didn't turn off at all, but that's not certain.

However, as soon as I finished charging, the problem returned immediately. Moreover, this problem does not appear on the account login screen. The drive starts to turn off only after logging into my account.
I only have one user, so I didn't check what happens if I log into another profile. However, in any case, it is desirable for me to restore my profile.

Core version: 4.15.0-163-generic

```
:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD2500BEVT-11ZCT0                   
    Serial Number:      WD-WXD0A7924648
    Firmware Revision:  11.01A11
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5
Standards:
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   488397168
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      238475 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      250059 MBytes (250 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = 8192 KBytes
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 128
    Recommended acoustic management value: 128, current value: 254
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            SET_MAX security extension
            Automatic Acoustic Management feature set
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
       *    Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Read/Write Long (AC1), obsolete
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    76min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 76min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 58714ff2add89232
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 0014ee
    Unique ID   : 2ad0741c2
Checksum: correct
```

```
:~$ sudo hdparm -v /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 multcount     = 16 (on)
 IO_support    =  1 (32-bit)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 30401/255/63, sectors = 488397168, start = 0
```

```
:~$ sudo smartctl -i -n standby /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [i686-linux-4.15.0-163-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA
Device Model:     WDC WD2500BEVT-11ZCT0
Serial Number:    WD-WXD0A7924648
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2ad0741c2
Firmware Version: 11.01A11
User Capacity:    250 059 350 016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.5, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sat Dec 18 02:45:03 2021 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
Power mode is:    ACTIVE or IDLE
```

```
:~$ sudo smartctl -i -n standby /dev/sda -P show
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [i686-linux-4.15.0-163-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Drive found in smartmontools Database.  Drive identity strings:
MODEL:              WDC WD2500BEVT-11ZCT0
FIRMWARE:           11.01A11
match smartmontools Drive Database entry:
MODEL REGEXP:       WDC WD((4|6|8|10|12|16|25)00BEVS|(8|12|16|25|32|40|50|64)00BEVT|7500KEVT|10TEVT)-.*
FIRMWARE REGEXP:    .*
MODEL FAMILY:       Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA
ATTRIBUTE OPTIONS:  None preset; no -v options are required.
```

```
:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
[sudo] password for wined: 
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [i686-linux-4.15.0-163-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Blue Serial ATA
Device Model:     WDC WD2500BEVT-11ZCT0
Serial Number:    WD-WXD0A7924648
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2ad0741c2
Firmware Version: 11.01A11
User Capacity:    250 059 350 016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.5, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sat Dec 18 02:59:17 2021 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 7500) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  90) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x303f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   152   145   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3400
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3261
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1313
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2523
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       900
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   193   193   000    Old_age   Always       -       21080
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   115   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0009   100   253   051    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 90 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 90 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 769 hours (32 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 77 00 60 40  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00600077 = 6291575

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 77 00 60 00 00      00:14:05.873  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 6f 00 60 00 00      00:14:05.872  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf fb 5d 00 00      00:14:05.871  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf 02 00 00 00      00:14:05.870  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 d7 02 00 00 00      00:14:05.870  READ DMA EXT

Error 89 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 769 hours (32 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 77 00 60 40  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00600077 = 6291575

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 77 00 60 00 00      00:14:02.680  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 6f 00 60 00 00      00:14:02.679  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf fb 5d 00 00      00:14:02.678  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf 02 00 00 00      00:14:02.677  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 d7 02 00 00 00      00:14:02.676  READ DMA EXT

Error 88 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 769 hours (32 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 77 00 60 40  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00600077 = 6291575

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 77 00 60 00 00      00:13:59.496  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 6f 00 60 00 00      00:13:59.495  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf fb 5d 00 00      00:13:59.494  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf 02 00 00 00      00:13:59.493  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 d7 02 00 00 00      00:13:59.492  READ DMA EXT

Error 87 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 769 hours (32 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 77 00 60 40  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00600077 = 6291575

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 77 00 60 00 00      00:13:56.475  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 6f 00 60 00 00      00:13:56.474  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf fb 5d 00 00      00:13:56.473  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf 02 00 00 00      00:13:56.472  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 d7 02 00 00 00      00:13:56.471  READ DMA EXT

Error 86 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 769 hours (32 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 77 00 60 40  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00600077 = 6291575

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 77 00 60 00 00      00:13:53.295  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 6f 00 60 00 00      00:13:53.294  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf fb 5d 00 00      00:13:53.293  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 bf 02 00 00 00      00:13:53.292  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 d7 02 00 00 00      00:13:53.291  READ DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               80%       849         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

```
:~$ sudo btrace /dev/sda
  8,0    0        0    87.351826880     0  m   N cfq267SN insert_request
  8,0    0        0    87.351831509     0  m   N cfq267SN add_to_rr
  8,0    0        0    87.351842530     0  m   N cfq267SN preempt
  8,0    0        0    87.351845341     0  m   N cfq1874SN slice expired t=1
  8,0    0        0    87.351849561     0  m   N cfq1874SN resid=99507703
  8,0    0        0    87.351856585     0  m   N served: vt=430839073124352 min_vt=430837039960064
  8,0    0        0    87.351862078     0  m   N cfq1874SN sl_used=496378 disp=1 charge=496378 iops=0 sect=8
  8,0    0        0    87.351864774     0  m   N cfq1874SN del_from_rr
  8,0    0        0    87.351874920     0  m   N cfq267SN set_active wl_class:0 wl_type:1
  8,0    0        0    87.351879994     0  m   N cfq267SN Not idling. st->count:1
  8,0    0        0    87.351882525     0  m   N cfq267SN dispatch_insert
  8,0    0        0    87.351889128     0  m   N cfq267SN dispatched a request
  8,0    0        0    87.351892195     0  m   N cfq267SN activate rq, drv=1
  8,0    0      460    87.351893471   267  D  WS 327649464 + 72 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      461    87.351936478   267  U   N [jbd2/sda5-8] 1
  8,0    0      462    87.352957578   267  A FWFS 327649536 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668480
  8,0    0      463    87.352971230   267  Q FWFS 327649536 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      464    87.353005271   267  G FWFS 327649536 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      465    87.353018363   267  I FWFS 327649536 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      466    87.353032349   267  D  FN [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    1      417    87.373874043  2456  C  FN 0 [0]
  8,0    1      418    87.373908114  2456  D  WS 327649536 + 8 [sakura]
  8,0    1      419    87.374374261  2456  C  WS 327649536 + 8 [0]
  8,0    1      420    87.374400718  2456  D  FN [sakura]
  8,0    1      421    87.393527020     0  C  FN 0 [0]
  8,0    1      422    87.393550552     0  C  WS 327649536 [0]
  8,0    1      423    87.395940821  1874  A  WS 173179208 + 8 <- (8,5) 5198152
  8,0    1      424    87.395946443  1874  Q  WS 173179208 + 8 [upowerd]
  8,0    1      425    87.395965518  1874  G  WS 173179208 + 8 [upowerd]
  8,0    1      426    87.395968347  1874  P   N [upowerd]
  8,0    1      427    87.395981755  1874  I  WS 173179208 + 8 [upowerd]
  8,0    1        0    87.395992993     0  m   N cfq1874SN insert_request
  8,0    1        0    87.395997170     0  m   N cfq1874SN add_to_rr
  8,0    1        0    87.396008002     0  m   N cfq1874SN preempt
  8,0    1        0    87.396010497     0  m   N cfq267SN slice expired t=1
  8,0    1        0    87.396013936     0  m   N cfq267SN resid=76802317
  8,0    1        0    87.396021090     0  m   N served: vt=431016027164672 min_vt=430839073124352
  8,0    1        0    87.396026763     0  m   N cfq267SN sl_used=43201670 disp=1 charge=43201670 iops=0 sect=72
  8,0    1        0    87.396029490     0  m   N cfq267SN del_from_rr
  8,0    1        0    87.396038137     0  m   N cfq1874SN set_active wl_class:0 wl_type:1
  8,0    1        0    87.396042425     0  m   N cfq1874SN Not idling. st->count:1
  8,0    1        0    87.396044854     0  m   N cfq1874SN dispatch_insert
  8,0    1        0    87.396050491     0  m   N cfq1874SN dispatched a request
  8,0    1        0    87.396053179     0  m   N cfq1874SN activate rq, drv=1
  8,0    1      428    87.396054467  1874  D  WS 173179208 + 8 [upowerd]
  8,0    1      429    87.396090079  1874  U   N [upowerd] 1
  8,0    1      430    87.396914392     0  C  WS 173179208 + 8 [0]
  8,0    1        0    87.396988750     0  m   N cfq1874SN complete rqnoidle 1
  8,0    1        0    87.396997008     0  m   N cfq1874SN set_slice=100000000
  8,0    1        0    87.397001911     0  m   N cfq1874SN Not idling. st->count:1
  8,0    1        0    87.397003891     0  m   N cfq schedule dispatch
  8,0    1      431    87.398233192     0  C  WS 327649544 + 80 [0]
  8,0    1        0    87.398274770     0  m   N cfq267SN complete rqnoidle 1
  8,0    1        0    87.398280662     0  m   N cfq267SN set_slice=120000000
  8,0    1        0    87.398284635     0  m   N cfq267SN Not idling. st->count:1
  8,0    1        0    87.398286161     0  m   N cfq schedule dispatch
  8,0    0      467    87.397440429   267  A  WS 327649544 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668488
  8,0    0      468    87.397447797   267  Q  WS 327649544 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      469    87.397467470   267  G  WS 327649544 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      470    87.397470486   267  P   N [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      471    87.397476902   267  A  WS 327649552 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668496
  8,0    0      472    87.397478049   267  Q  WS 327649552 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      473    87.397482693   267  M  WS 327649552 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      474    87.397485420   267  A  WS 327649560 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668504
  8,0    0      475    87.397486669   267  Q  WS 327649560 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      476    87.397488095   267  M  WS 327649560 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      477    87.397490205   267  A  WS 327649568 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668512
  8,0    0      478    87.397491469   267  Q  WS 327649568 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      479    87.397493043   267  M  WS 327649568 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      480    87.397496793   267  A  WS 327649576 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668520
  8,0    0      481    87.397498087   267  Q  WS 327649576 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      482    87.397499631   267  M  WS 327649576 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      483    87.397502087   267  A  WS 327649584 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668528
  8,0    0      484    87.397503312   267  Q  WS 327649584 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      485    87.397504747   267  M  WS 327649584 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      486    87.397506950   267  A  WS 327649592 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668536
  8,0    0      487    87.397508187   267  Q  WS 327649592 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      488    87.397509614   267  M  WS 327649592 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      489    87.397511648   267  A  WS 327649600 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668544
  8,0    0      490    87.397512894   267  Q  WS 327649600 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      491    87.397514432   267  M  WS 327649600 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      492    87.397516476   267  A  WS 327649608 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668552
  8,0    0      493    87.397517710   267  Q  WS 327649608 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      494    87.397519259   267  M  WS 327649608 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      495    87.397521685   267  A  WS 327649616 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668560
  8,0    0      496    87.397522919   267  Q  WS 327649616 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      497    87.397524328   267  M  WS 327649616 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      498    87.397534383   267  I  WS 327649544 + 80 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0        0    87.397545955     0  m   N cfq267SN insert_request
  8,0    0        0    87.397550511     0  m   N cfq267SN add_to_rr
  8,0    0        0    87.397561364     0  m   N cfq267SN preempt
  8,0    0        0    87.397563907     0  m   N cfq1874SN slice expired t=1
  8,0    0        0    87.397567678     0  m   N cfq1874SN resid=99428376
  8,0    0        0    87.397574615     0  m   N served: vt=431018384670720 min_vt=431016027164672
  8,0    0        0    87.397580110     0  m   N cfq1874SN sl_used=575563 disp=1 charge=575563 iops=0 sect=8
  8,0    0        0    87.397582795     0  m   N cfq1874SN del_from_rr
  8,0    0        0    87.397592043     0  m   N cfq267SN set_active wl_class:0 wl_type:1
  8,0    0        0    87.397596648     0  m   N cfq267SN Not idling. st->count:1
  8,0    0        0    87.397599399     0  m   N cfq267SN dispatch_insert
  8,0    0        0    87.397604952     0  m   N cfq267SN dispatched a request
  8,0    0        0    87.397607910     0  m   N cfq267SN activate rq, drv=1
  8,0    0      499    87.397609048   267  D  WS 327649544 + 80 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      500    87.397650402   267  U   N [jbd2/sda5-8] 1
  8,0    0      501    87.398359845   267  A FWFS 327649624 + 8 <- (8,5) 159668568
  8,0    0      502    87.398366496   267  Q FWFS 327649624 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      503    87.398383431   267  G FWFS 327649624 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      504    87.398390275   267  I FWFS 327649624 + 8 [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    0      505    87.398396661   267  D  FN [jbd2/sda5-8]
  8,0    1      432    87.424264655  2823  C  FN 0 [0]
  8,0    1      433    87.424299921  2823  D  WS 327649624 + 8 [blkparse]
  8,0    1      434    87.424763377  2456  C  WS 327649624 + 8 [0]
  8,0    1      435    87.424788158  2456  D  FN [sakura]
  8,0    1      436    87.438554571     0  C  FN 0 [0]
  8,0    1      437    87.438570708     0  C  WS 327649624 [0]
  8,0    0      506    89.443537048   354  A   W 168072344 + 8 <- (8,5) 91288
  8,0    0      507    89.443542733   354  Q   W 168072344 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      508    89.443564170   354  G   W 168072344 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      509    89.443566824   354  P   N [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      510    89.443596147   354  A   W 169301160 + 8 <- (8,5) 1320104
  8,0    0      511    89.443597537   354  Q   W 169301160 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      512    89.443605449   354  G   W 169301160 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      513    89.443652802   354  A   W 273531120 + 8 <- (8,5) 105550064
  8,0    0      514    89.443654282   354  Q   W 273531120 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      515    89.443663040   354  G   W 273531120 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      516    89.443674699   354  A   W 189781784 + 8 <- (8,5) 21800728
  8,0    0      517    89.443675906   354  Q   W 189781784 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      518    89.443682220   354  G   W 189781784 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      519    89.443693283   354  A   W 189783192 + 8 <- (8,5) 21802136
  8,0    0      520    89.443694475   354  Q   W 189783192 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      521    89.443702134   354  G   W 189783192 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      522    89.443713399   354  A   W 189784408 + 8 <- (8,5) 21803352
  8,0    0      523    89.443714609   354  Q   W 189784408 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      524    89.443724170   354  G   W 189784408 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      525    89.443754787   354  A   W 189787248 + 40 <- (8,5) 21806192
  8,0    0      526    89.443756147   354  Q   W 189787248 + 40 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      527    89.443764929   354  G   W 189787248 + 40 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      528    89.443785812   354  A   W 189787536 + 24 <- (8,5) 21806480
  8,0    0      529    89.443787124   354  Q   W 189787536 + 24 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      530    89.443794588   354  G   W 189787536 + 24 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      531    89.443806274   354  A   W 189787704 + 8 <- (8,5) 21806648
  8,0    0      532    89.443807601   354  Q   W 189787704 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      533    89.443814842   354  G   W 189787704 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      534    89.443831007   354  A   W 189787784 + 8 <- (8,5) 21806728
  8,0    0      535    89.443832289   354  Q   W 189787784 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      536    89.443840117   354  G   W 189787784 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      537    89.443868425   354  A   W 189787872 + 16 <- (8,5) 21806816
  8,0    0      538    89.443869878   354  Q   W 189787872 + 16 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      539    89.443877938   354  G   W 189787872 + 16 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      540    89.443883262   354  A   W 189787984 + 8 <- (8,5) 21806928
  8,0    0      541    89.443884285   354  Q   W 189787984 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      542    89.443890376   354  G   W 189787984 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      543    89.443932546   354  A  WM 167981064 + 8 <- (8,5) 8
  8,0    0      544    89.443934060   354  Q  WM 167981064 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      545    89.443943122   354  G  WM 167981064 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      546    89.443956521   354  A  WM 172175384 + 8 <- (8,5) 4194328
  8,0    0      547    89.443957953   354  Q  WM 172175384 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]
  8,0    0      548    89.443964523   354  G  WM 172175384 + 8 [kworker/u8:4]

Total (8,0):
 Reads Queued:           0,        0KiB  Writes Queued:         181,      872KiB
 Read Dispatches:       24,        0KiB  Write Dispatches:      107,      872KiB
 Reads Requeued:         0       Writes Requeued:         0
 Reads Completed:       24,        0KiB  Writes Completed:      119,      872KiB
 Read Merges:            0,        0KiB  Write Merges:           74,      296KiB
 PC Reads Queued:        0,        0KiB  PC Writes Queued:        0,        0KiB
 PC Read Disp.:         36,        5KiB  PC Write Disp.:          0,        0KiB
 PC Reads Req.:          0       PC Writes Req.:          0
 PC Reads Compl.:       36       PC Writes Compl.:        0
 IO unplugs:            29           Timer unplugs:           0

Throughput (R/W): 0KiB/s / 9KiB/s
Events (8,0): 1982 entries
Skips: 0 forward (0 -   0.0%)
```

I still do not understand why this is happening with the HDD.

I have tried:

- `sudo vi /etc/smartd.conf` (changing -n mode)
- Different numbers in `sudo hdparm -S 129 -B 120 /dev/sda`

None of this worked.

Interestingly, even if I boot with an older kernel version, the HDD shutdown problem persists. At the same time, the Wi-FI adapter, the display driver does not work (the background image is simply stretched), but the problem with the constant shutdown of the disk remains.

**What is the problem that caused the HDD to instantly (without any timeout) turn off when it is idle?**

**How can I fix this problem?**

Comment: Note that booting an older kernel also requires you to have older modules, i.e. it's not enough to just restore vmlinuz and initrd - you also need the matching /lib/modules/$kver as well. Without them, it'll still boot but as you saw it won't have Wi-Fi drivers, etc.